# Use the mapper for the base class to map the child class

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have the following class structure

```
class MapFromBase {
}

class MapFromChild extends MapFromBase {
}

class MapToBase {
}

class MapToChild extends MapToBase {
}

@Mapper
interface Mapper {
  @Mappings(/* a lot of mappings */)
  MapToBase mapBase (MapFromBase value);

  MapToChild mapChild (MapFromChild value);
}
```

Is there a way to make the `mapChild` mapper use the `mapBase` mapper for all the fields inherited from the base class without copying all the mappings by hand?

Comment: Create a method and override/call parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MapStruct has a mechanism to [inherit configurations](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_reusing_mapping_configurations). In your case, I would define a shared mapping config (annotated `@MapperConfig`) in stead of inheritance of mappers and include this shared config in your `@Mapping`. This shared config can then be used by `@MapFromChild` and `@MapFromBase`. This way you use composition in stead of inheritance.

The shared config can also be reverse-inherited by `@MapToBase` and `@MapToChild`.

If you use [1.3Beta](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#shared-configurations), there are new options to inherit automatically all options in a mapper (and the reverse ones)

Answer (score 0):

You have to link MapFromChild and MapToChild. You can use generic marker for it.

```
class ChildType {        
}
class Child extends ChildType {
}
class SuperChild extends ChildType {
}
class OtherChild extends ChildType {
}

class MapFromBase<T extends ChildType> {
}

class MapFromChild extends MapFromBase<Child> {
}

class MapToBase<T extends ChildType> {
}

class MapToChild extends MapToBase<Child>  {
}

@Mapper
interface Mapper <X extends ChildType> {
    MapToBase<X> universalMap (MapFromBase<X> value);
}
```

Also ChildType could be an interface.

Comment: Code-only answers aren't usually great; perhaps consider adding an explanation.